# How to retrieve shell output from within i_CTRL_R in vim?

Tags: vim

When in insert mode in vim, I often do `CTRL-R` and retrieve a register content.

I like to be able to retrieve text that's not currently in a buffer, like the output of the shell command, `pwd`.

I was under the impression I could hit `i_CTRL_R ! pwd` sequence, but  `i_CTRL_R` can only takes a register.

The expression register `=` seems to be the only way to compute things dynamically, but I don't know what is the minimum number of key-strokes to get the `=` register to be populated with a shell output, or env variables.

Vimmers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert environment variables directly with:

```
<C-r>=$PATH
```

For inserting the output of shell commands you will need `:help system()` if you absolutely need to stay in insert mode:

```
<C-r>=system('ls')
```

If you don't mind leaving insert mode temporarily, you can use `:help :read`:

```
<C-o>:r!ls<CR>
```